# Google cloud architecture for new project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on a project that we are going to put on Google Cloud.

There will be a member requirement so logins and profiles to store. Members will make projects that will be linked to their accounts. Other members can join these projects etc. Its not overly complex but I need it to be fast and scalable from the off.

I have a few (simple) questions about the best setup to go for.

Do I have a PHP front end if PHP is only in beta? Do I just use Python for the front end? Is there a better framework than others to use?

Do I create an App Engine API for the front end to call using Python or Java or something else?

Which database do I use? Do I go down the Compute Engine/MongoDB approach or just go straight for Google datastore? (MySQL is disregarded here)

Do I use a shared memcache or get a dedicated one?

These sort of things. It appears using Google Cloud is 'fairly' straight forward but would appreciate some pointers from those in the know who have already get their hands dirty, in a virtual sense of course!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This broad, many-questions discussion is not really good for Stackoverflow's Q&A format -- I recommend you take it instead to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine .

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have four many-faceted Qs -- and apparently you **aren't** taking them to Google Groups so let me do my best here.

> Do I have a PHP front end if PHP is only in beta? Do I just use Python
>   for the front end? Is there a better framework than others to use?

For guaranteed solidity use Python or Java - PHP and Go aren't **quite** as mature yet.  Many Python frameworks are fine, from the very-lightweight `webapp2` that comes with App Engine, through intermediate-weight ones such as "flask", all the way to rich "django".  I'm personally a "frameworks shd stay out of my way!" guy so `webapp2` is my own favorite.

> Do I create an App Engine API for the front end to call using Python
>   or Java or something else?

Python and Java are both fully supported and stable.  I personally of course prefer Python, but, hey!, that's just me!  Endpoints, if that's what you mean by "an App Engine API", is also equally well supported each way, with Python perhaps a tad ahead in integration with the datastore thanks to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/tree/master/endpoints_proto_datastore .

> Which database do I use? Do I go down the Compute Engine/MongoDB
>   approach or just go straight for Google datastore? (MySQL is
>   disregarded here)

I think the GAE datastore (with add-ons as needed, e.g to shunt images and videos off to Cloud Storage, or structured data for search including geo functionality to the Search API) is going to serve you fine.

> Do I use a shared memcache or get a dedicated one?

Start with the shared (free) variety, then once you have it all working design and run stress load-tests and check how they perform with that vs a dedicated (paid) version.  Do **data-based** decisions -- let the numbers guide you: how much better are you getting by paying $X/month for dedicated cache?  Decide accordingly!-)